# Connecting to Sharepoint Services 3 via SDK: Getting 500 - Internal Server Error on ExecuteQuery()

Tags: c#, sharepoint

This is my first time using the Sharepoint SDK, and I'm having a hard time getting things connected...

The background is that the Sharepoint site is the Project portal in TFS 2010.  It is Sharepoint Services 3.0.

I have a fairly simple function that I'm trying to run:

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    using (SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext("http://<hostname>/sites/Projects"))
    {
      SP.Web web = ctx.Web;

      ctx.Load(web);
      ctx.Load(web.Lists);

      ctx.ExecuteQuery();

      foreach (var list in web.Lists)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("List Name: {0}", list.Title);
      }

    }

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

On the ExecuteQuery() call, it returns a 500 - Internal Server Error.  Any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using Sharepoint 2010 SDK code, not 2007 code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408569.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian pointing out SharePoint Services 3.0 do not supprt client side OM implemented in SharePoint 2010.

With SharePoint Services 3.0/MOSS 2007 you need to use Web Services - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824213(v=office.12).aspx